# Magento2 - SEO strength and SEO Architecture

Tags: magento-enterprise, javascript, magento2, seo, requirejs

I have just installed Magento2 EE and noticed that the Front-End is built upon the default template and the luna template.

The page renders lots of ajax calls which get the html files of the templates. These templates have code calls like:

```
<% if(data.title){ %>
<h1 class="modal-title"
data-role="title"><%= data.title %></h1>
<% } %>
```

Is this handlebars.js? I also see the use of RequireJS, KnockoutJS and packaged versions of jQuery. What is all this JavaScript and AJAX calls going to do to benefit SEO?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the end after all that dynamic JS and loading you get correct valid HTML code which can be crawled by Google and there is no any real difference to Magento 1 or any other CMS. Future more Google increase algorithms every day and they trying to catch all JS same as end user see it, so even if with full page cache some parts will be loaded dynamically - Google will understand that.

And yes, this is [handlebars.js](http://handlebarsjs.com/) on templates. Here is good track to understand the situation [Handlebars.js and SEO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7685490/handlebars-js-and-seo) SO question point us to official Google answer about [Ajax Crawling](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.de/2015/10/deprecating-our-ajax-crawling-scheme.html) :

> Times have changed. Today, as long as you're not blocking Googlebot from crawling your JavaScript or CSS files, we are generally able to render and understand your web pages like modern browsers. To reflect this improvement, we recently updated our technical Webmaster Guidelines to recommend against disallowing Googlebot from crawling your site's CSS or JS files.

Magento 2 out of box have some cool SEO features like schema.org micro-formats, proper canonical tags etc. You can read more about Magento 2 SEO features in our summary https://firebearstudio.com/blog/magento-2-seo.html

Comment: Thanks. I guess I kind of knew this. Take AngularJS for example. Backed by Google Engineers and the way things are heading; a JavaScript driven world.

Answer (score 2):

In my point of view, this is only increase website speed. So minimize, because in 2017 mobile friendly site should be important.... So egnor max CSS and JavaScript..

Answer (score 1):

Magento 2 use javascript rendering mostly for user specific content. And page like CMS, Product, Category rendered on server side. As result any search bot can retrieve content in static html format. So no any problem from SEO point of view.